# Numerically solving the Schrodinger equation via finite difference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics

This is not strictly a question about physics but about the numerical solution to 
a physics problem. I am solving the Schrodinger equation via finite difference, via the substitution

[image]

I solved this using Mathematica for the case that $V(x) = 0$ and get the correct eigenvalues. I find the eigenvectors and plot them via

```
d2dx[n_] := 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -2, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, 
     Band[{2, 1}] -> 1}, {n, n}]/(1/n^2);
evecs[n_, m_] := Last@Eigenvectors[N[-d2dx[n]], m]
ListPlot[evecs[100, 1], Joined -> True]
ListPlot[evecs[100, 2], Joined -> True]
ListPlot[evecs[100, 3], Joined -> True]
```

But the results look like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The profiles are correct but of course it shouldn't be oscillating in this way. Why am I seeing these oscillations and how do I get the correct eigenvectors?

Comment: As far as I understand, the equation itself does not fix the eigenfunction sign, so the numerical procedure may yield both signs on the same plot. If you connect only positive-valued points in the first plot, you will get a $sin(\pi x/100)$, I guess.

Comment: Each plot shows the last eigenvector . Have you tried plotting the first eigenvectors? I recall when I was doing this the eigenvectors started as smooth solutions and as $m$ increased they started looking like your plots.

Comment: I'd refer you to [this Mathematics SE Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018197/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-a-tridiagonal-block-matrix?rq=1) on the subject of Toeplitz matrices.  I'm pretty sure you'd get better answers on Mathematics SE to a question like this.

Comment: Or perhaps [mathematica.se] for analysis of the code you've written.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate:  [on SE.Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173669/46865).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a computational implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the Mathematica code, the answer can be found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173669/solving-the-schrodinger-equation-by-exact-diagonalization/173672#173672.

The eigenvectors are organized from greatest eigenvalue to least. The solution is to reverse the list of eigenvectors then take the `m`'th vector from the list. It can be fixed by replacing with

```
evecs[n_, m_] := Reverse[Eigenvectors[N[-d2dx[n]]]][[m]]
```

Comment: This looks like a link-only answer.  Links are great for support, but it's typically best to include the content in the answer.

Comment: Since the answer is that the problem was not related to physics would it be better to add the answer or delete the question?

Comment: Ya know, I'm not too sure what the policy might be.  Cross-site duplicate posts seem to have a fuzzy handling.

Comment: According to [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/888/142085), it sounds like deleting cross-site duplicates may be the way to go unless there's a specific reason to have the same question on multiple SE's.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm going to go ahead and delete the post then.